# Original Array value after modification

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
var a = ["11", "22", "46", "22", "11", "55"];

console.log(a); // [ '11', '22', '46', '22', '11', '55' ]

// Calculates my values
var b = a.map(function(num) {
  return num.split('')
    .map(Number)
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });
});
console.log(b); // [ 2, 4, 10, 4, 2, 10 ]

// Finds my biggest value
var c = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  if (b[i] > c) {
    c = b[i];
  }
}
console.log(c); // 10

// Sorts my array
var d = b;
d.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(d); // [ 2, 2, 4, 4, 10, 10 ]
```

I am having a problem here. The `var d` tells me about these following arrays `[ 2, 2, 4, 4, 10, 10 ]`. They originally come from this array `["11","22","46","22","11","55"]`. I am also sorting them out. So at the end in `var d` I am receiving two 10s at the end of my array. Let's say that `d[4]` originally came from `a[2]` and `d[5]` came from `a[5]`. How can I make the code tell me 10's original value from my first array. Let's say we get `2, 2, 4, 4, 10, 10`. I want this last 10 from right side value to tell me it came from `"55"`. Is there a way for me to do that?

Comment: Probably only with `objects`, using an array of `{value:'',origin:'', ...}` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other solution from Joseph the Dreamer points to the right direction, lacks it the concrete wanted result of the question.

This proposal uses an array with objects and keeps the former sort order with `pos` and the wanted cobined number.

After sorting, you can access the last element and get the original value from the new array.

```js
var a = ["11", "22", "46", "22", "11", "55"],
    b = a.map(function (aa, i) {
        return {
            value: aa,
            pos: i,
            number: aa.split('').map(Number).reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b }, 0),
        };
    });

b.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.number - b.number;
});

document.write(b[b.length - 1].value);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(b, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```js
function myfun(a) {
    var b = a.map(function (aa, i) {
            return {
                value: aa,
                pos: i,
                number: aa.replace(/-/g, '').split('').map(Number).reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b }, 0),
            };
        });

    b.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.number - b.number;
    });
    return b;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myfun(['1-2-3-4', '5-67-7-8', '2-3545-4-6-8-1', '3-3-4-1-3-4', "3-2-4-5-7", '2-3-4-5-7']), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: What if I have "-" characters between my digits like "1-1" and "2-2" I did add new variables such as .toString().replace(/-/g, ""); and then another one with .split(',');  var b = a.toString().replace(/-/g, "");
 // 
 var c = b.split(',');  but at the end my original value is displayed without any "-" so it's showing me 22 instead of 2-2.

Comment: use `split('-')` without replace.

Comment: But if I remove replace, the code is not working. function myfun(a)
{
 var b = a.toString().replace(/-/g, "");
 var c = b.split(',');
    d = c.map(function (aa, i) {
        return {
            value: aa,
            pos: i,
            number: aa.split('').map(Number).reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b }, 0),
        };
    });
    d.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.number - b.number;
});

console.log(d[d.length - 1].value);
//console.log( JSON.stringify(d, 0, 4));
console.log(d);

}
myfun(['1-2-3-4', '5-67-7-8', '2-3545-4-6-8-1' ,'3-3-4-1-3-4',"3-2-4-5-7",'2-3-4-5-7']);

Comment: why do you convert the whole array to a string and then do the rest. anyway please see the second proposal.

Comment: Thank you Nina. :)

Answer (score 2):

On your `a.map`, make it return an object with a property containing the original value, and a property you want modified. In the following case, `original` will be the value that is to be untouched while `value` is the one you'll be working on. Further operations should work with `value` and preserve `original`.

```
a.map(function(num) {
  return {
    original: num,
    value: //stuff
  };
});
```

Comment: Sorry Joseph I am trying to write the code but I am not having any luck. So this this my code that I have change right? I am just thinking how without returning any errors.  a.map(function(num) {
  return num.split('')
    .map(Number)
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    });
});